# window.scroll does not work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, scroll, window

I have the following code which works on all browsers besides on `IE11`. any idea what might be the issue?

```js
function scrollIntoWarranty() {
  var offset = 50;
  var el = document.querySelector("#tr_tab_2");
  window.scroll({ top: (el.offsetTop - offset), left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="scrollIntoWarranty(); return false;">
  Go to warranty
</a>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<div id="tr_tab_2">Warranty</div>
```

Comment: no, it's the opposite, IE is no longer supported :))

Comment: @MisterJojo couldn't agree more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollBehavior is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior) by IE

Try this

```js
function scrollIntoWarranty() {
  var el = document.querySelector("#tr_tab_2");
  if ('scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style) { // behavior is not supported by IE
    var offset = 50;
    window.scroll({ top: (el.offsetTop - offset), left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  } else {
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="scrollIntoWarranty(); return false;">
  Go to warranty
</a>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<div id="tr_tab_2">Warranty</div>
```

Comment: You are a legend, and I truly hate `IE`. Thanks!

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit.